# How do I align my div like this?

Tags: html, css

This is an image of what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

and this is what I currently have: [image: Hello]

Does anyone know how I could get the "Jan" and "schreef om 15 Januari 2013 om 12:32" part on one line, next to the top of the image, the lorem ipsum beneath it and finally, the "Footer" beneath the image?

Here's my code:

```
    <aside class="previewPost" id="HTMLPreview">
                  <article>
                    <div id="imageDiv">
                        <img src="img/avatar.png" alt="Avatar"  width="150" height="150" id="imageHTML"/>
                    </div>

                    <div id="firstNameDiv">
                        Jan
                    </div>

                    <div id="dateDiv">
                        schreef om 15 Januari 2013 om 12:32
                    </div>

                    <div id="postDiv">
                        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
                        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate 
                        velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
                    </div>

                    <div id="fullname">
                    Jan met de korte achternaam (24)
                    </div>

                    <div id="workDiv">
                    student
                    </div>


                </article>
            </aside>
```

and here's the CSS of the sidebar:

```
 .previewPost{
width: 40%;
float: left;
margin-left: 2%;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-ms-border-radius: 5px;
-o-border-radius: 5px;
background-color: #FFF; 
padding: 2% 3%;
margin-bottom: 2%;
}
```

Could anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

"Jan" and "schreef om 15 Januari 2013 om 12:32" are separated in 2 different divs. If you want them on same row just add  `display: inline-block`

```
#firstNameDiv, #dateDiv{
     display: inline-block   
}
```

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/nLbpuesm/1/)